# Dynamic model namespace in laravel lumen package

Tags: php, laravel, namespaces, package, lumen

I am building a laravel lumen package. In the package there is a service provider which uses instance of User model in a function. I used **App\User** as namespace there.

Now,
If actual User Model is placed in different namespace eg. **App\Models\User** my package gives an error of undefined class User.

How can I get this User model instance in proper way without any error?

Comment: You can set it in configs and ask for users to set it according to thier needs

Comment: I can but that comes after the installation from composer. The error shows right while installing the package which looks like an error to user.

Comment: Rehman can you post a code?

Comment: $user = App\User::find($credentials->sub); this line I wrote in the service provider of my package and while install the package it says App\User not found on the console

Comment: post the full code in question

Comment: Thank you.
There is nothing with code actually. It just about not finding the model in the given namespace.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the User model location from the [`config/auth.php`](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/config/auth.php#L70). However if the application uses a different authentication method, this will not work.

I think your best option is to [make the class path to the User model configurable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/packages#configuration).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I edit the question. The package is for lumen where no config files by default.